# C++ Using already instantiated object

Tags: c++

Is there a way in C++ to make the compiler first instantiate an object from a class so I could use it in another class. Or what is the elegant way of dealing with that problem?

For example:

`A.h`

```
class A
{
   int x;
   A() 
   { 
      //x is being read from a file 
   }
   void printX();
};
```

`B.h`

```
class B
{
   void somefunction() 
   {
      objectA.printX();
   }
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
main()
{
   A objectA;
   ...
   B objB;
   objB.somefunction();
}
```

Comment: Maybe pass `objectA` as a parameter to `B::someFunction()`?

Comment: You may add B as member to A or bass objectA to constructor of objB.

Comment: Make `B` have an `A` member? Hold a reference to an `A`? It depends on your use-case, which is unknown to us.

Comment: you may require a reference to an `A` object when constructing `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to pass object B a reference to the object you are trying to use, such as...

Note: When you pass objects as function arguments that are not just POD, it is best practice to pass them by constant reference if you aren't modifying them (that way you aren't making a copy of the whole object, which could be large, you just pass a pointer). However in this case, as it is now a const reference, you can only call const functions which is why I made your printX const. Presumably printX isn't modifying A, so it should be const.

`A.h`

```
class A
{
   int x;
   A() 
   { 
      //x is being read from a file 
   }
   void printX() const;
};
```

`B.h`

```
class B
{
   void somefunction(const A& objectA) 
   {
      objectA.printX();
   }
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
main()
{
   A objectA;
   ...
   B objB;
   objB.somefunction(objectA);
}
```